# How to make an input field wrap text?

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately, my input field does not wrap the entered text once the end of the field is reached. It just keeps going instead (expanding). How can I make the text inside an input field wrap once it reached the end of the field, so it can create a new line and go on from there? I attached a picture as an example from Twitter:

https://ibb.co/dgjzJg8

I couldn't really find a good solution in other related topics, except for using textarea, but I do not want to use this in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. You cannot do that because it's not possible with text field which is by nature a single line. type=text does not support carriage returns or breaks. Just like you can't type in a checkbox. It just doesn't work that way. Web elements have specific features, functions, and capabilities.

So, you will have to use the textarea field instead.